# Saving a file without the chance of premature shutdown corrupting it

Tags: node.js, database

I am using NodeJS, but this is kind of a general question.

I use a JSON file for a simple database structure.
At run-time, this file is re-saved every N seconds with the actual live JS object.

One time power cut off, and after restarting my machine, the file was empty, all data gone forever.

After that I tried using 2 files.
First the main file is renamed to another name synchronously, and then the original file is saved.
This way the data is always there, even if the rename fails.
After the rename, even if the write fails, the renamed file is there.
Even though this is using sychronous calls and should work...power cut off again, and all of the data was lost, again.

Is there a smarter solution to save files without all of the original data getting lost if electricity decides to go away?

Comment: You cannot prevent file system corruption from unexpected power interruption purely from your application level code.  You can increase the likelihood that there is some data still available on disk by how you structure your application code (generally by leaving intact backup copies of good data around), but you can't guarantee that any file you're writing to is not corrupted if the power is cut while writing.  If you want to protect against that, then get a UPS for your server and do a graceful shutdown of the server once it goes onto the UPS power.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something with STM? I don't know about STM in node.js, but is a way to ether have the new or the old version of your file. Another option would be to check how are you making the renamed and the new files. It sounds to me it should work, so maybe the problem is how you implement it.